# Change map language in GoogleMaps instance

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

When I create instance of GoogleMaps from google_maps_flutter package, the Google Maps widget language of English (all the cities and street names are presented in English).

How do I change this language to Hebrew or any other language?

Comment: Did you find solution to this? I am making website using flutter and language there is also English only

Answer (score 1):

It's depending on the device language